# Простая программа "создания" героя RPG. Как можно улучшить/сократить этот код без потери функиональности?

Tags: python-3.x, инспекция-кода, рефакторинг

Всем привет.
Есть задача:
Создание героя/героини RPG: дано 10 пунктов, которые можно распределить между четырьмя характеристиками: Сила, Здоровье, Мудрость, Ловкость.
Пусть будет возможно не только брать пункты из общего «пула», но и возвращать их туда из характеристик, которым решено присвоить иные значения.

Есть код. "Код большой, как бегемот". Как можно его сократить/улучшить без потери функциональности?

```
hero_choice = None
temporarily_choice = None
one_skill = 1

strength_hero = 0
agility_hero = 0
wisdom_hero = 0
health_hero = 0

list_params = [1] * 10
main_list_navikov = list(list_params)
ostalos_navikov = len(main_list_navikov)

def skills_of_hero():
    print("\n\n Осталось очков навыков:", ostalos_navikov)
    print("\nУровень Силы героя/героини:", strength_hero)
    print("Уровень Здоровья героя/героини:", health_hero)
    print("Уровень Мудрости героя/героини:", wisdom_hero)
    print("Уровень Ловкости героя/героини:", agility_hero)

def exit_choice():
    print("\n Получился герой/героиня с такими навыками: ")
    skills_of_hero()
    input("\n\tНажмите Enter для выхода")
    exit()

def make_hero(hero_choice):
    global temporarily_choice
    global strength_hero
    global health_hero
    global wisdom_hero
    global agility_hero

    print("\n Вы выбрали:", hero_choice , "сей выбор приемлем.")

    if hero_choice == 1:
        temporarily_choice = strength_hero
        vivod = "Сила"
    elif hero_choice == 2:
        temporarily_choice = health_hero
        vivod = "Здоровье"
    elif hero_choice == 3:
        temporarily_choice = wisdom_hero
        vivod = "Мудрость"
    elif hero_choice == 4:
        temporarily_choice = agility_hero
        vivod = "Ловкость"

    print("\n Выбор:", hero_choice , "означает:", vivod)
    plus_or_minus_skill = input("Введите знак без кавычек. Вы хотите прибавить '+' или убавить '-' параметр: ")

    if plus_or_minus_skill not in ("+", "-"):
        print("\n Введён не '+' или '-' Выходим.")
        exit_choice()

    if plus_or_minus_skill == '+':
        if one_skill in main_list_navikov:
            temporarily_choice += 1
            main_list_navikov.remove(one_skill)
        else:
            print("\n Похоже, навыки закончились/все распределены.")
    else:
        if temporarily_choice != 0:
            temporarily_choice -= 1
            main_list_navikov.append(one_skill)
        else:
            print("\n Нельзя уменьшить! Навык и так слишком мал!")

    if hero_choice == 1:
        strength_hero = temporarily_choice
        return(strength_hero)

    elif hero_choice == 2:
        health_hero = temporarily_choice
        return(health_hero)

    elif hero_choice == 3:
        wisdom_hero = temporarily_choice
        return(wisdom_hero)

    elif hero_choice == 4:
        agility_hero = temporarily_choice
        return(agility_hero)

print('''
Программа создания персонажа RPG.
У вас есть 10 пунктов навыков, распределите их между параметрами: Здоровье, Сила, Мудрость, Ловкость.
''')

while hero_choice != 0:
    print("\n\n Текущее количество очков навыков: ", ostalos_navikov)

    print('''
    Таблица выбора:
                1 - Добавить/убавить Силу.
                2 - Добавить/убавить Здоровье.
                3 - Добавить/убавить Мудрость.
                4 - Добавить/убавить Ловкость.
                    0 - Выход из меню.
''')

    hero_choice = int(input("Выберете один из вышеозначенных пунктов: "))
    if hero_choice not in range(5):
        print("\n Колдунство не сработало! Попробуйте ещё раз...")
        continue
    exit_choice() if hero_choice == 0 else make_hero(hero_choice)

    ostalos_navikov = len(main_list_navikov)
    skills_of_hero()
```

Answer (score 1):

А переписать считается за улучшить? Писал с использованием ООП. 70 строк включая отступы. Хочу заметить что ваш вариант с добавлением по одному очку - боль. Добавление, удаление очков - уже не такая боль но все же, зачем заставлять считать пользователя если есть машина?)

Вы вводите **желаемое** количество очков и программа говорит сколько осталось.

Основная идея иметь менеджер который следит за "коллекцией", добавляет в нее новые навыки, удаляет (при необходимости можно реализовать), а так же знает сколько осталось очков, которые можно распределить в коллекции.

И собственно сами скиллы. Каждый знает о своем имени, своем id и своих очках.

Я заметил что Вы только учитесь по этому использовал штуки вроде `.isdigit()` и `raise Exception()`. Погуглите, если вы чего то не знаете или спросите в комментариях.

```
class SkillManager():
    def __repr__(self):
        # ", " - для вывода через запятую или
        # "\n" - для вывода в столбик
        return "\n".join('{0}. {1}: {2}'.format(key, self.skills[key].name, value) for key, value in self.skills.items())

    def __init__(self):
        self.all_points = 10
        self.skills = {}

    def add_skill(self, skill_id, name):
        self.skills[skill_id] = Skill(skill_id, name)

    def get_skill(self, skill_id):
        if skill_id in self.skills:
            return self.skills.get(skill_id, None)
        else:
            raise Exception("\nНесуществующий id!")


    def change_skill(self, skill_id, delta):
        if ((self.all_points + (self.skills[skill_id].points - delta)) >= 0):
            if skill_id in self.skills:
                self.all_points += self.skills[skill_id].points - delta
                self.skills[skill_id].points = delta
            else:
                raise Exception("\nНесуществующий id!")
        else:
            raise Exception("\nНедостаточно очков")

class Skill():
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.points)

    def __init__(self, skill_id, name):
        self.skill_id = skill_id
        self.name = name
        self.points = 0

skillManager = SkillManager()
stats = {1: 'сила', 2: 'ловкость', 3: 'мудрость', 4: 'здоровье'}
i = True

for skill_id, name in stats.items():
    skillManager.add_skill(skill_id, name)

while i:
    print("У вас: {0} доступных очков".format(skillManager.all_points))
    print(skillManager)

    print("")
    i = input("Выберите необходимый навык: ")

    if i.isdigit():
        i = int(i)

        try:
            print("\nВы изменяете навык: {0}".format(skillManager.get_skill(i).name))
            points = input("Укажите желаемое количество очков: ")

            if points.isdigit():
                points = int(points)
                if points < 0:
                    raise Exception("Уровень навыка не может быть отрицаиельным!")

                skillManager.change_skill(i, points)

        except Exception as error:
            print(error.args[0])

    elif i:
        print("\nПросто введите цифру навыка")
```

В живую можно поиграться [тут](https://repl.it/repls/ConventionalThunderousStinkbug)

Answer (score 0):

Вроде бы ничего из функционала не потерял
Основная идея - номер пункта меню указывает на элемент списка skill_l, который содержит название характеристики и выданные ей очки.
Соответственно, уходим от необходимости кучи if или switch-a при обработке номера пункта меню

```
just_do_it = True
skill_l = [[0, 0, 0, 0],['сила', 'ловкость', 'мудрость', 'здоровье']]
skill_p = 10


def show_stats():
    global skill_l
    global skill_p
    print('Текущие характеристики:')
    print('Свободно очков характеристик - ', skill_p)
    for i in range(len(skill_l[0])):
        print(skill_l[1][i], '-', skill_l[0][i])


def show_list():
    global skill_l
    for i in range(len(skill_l[0])):
        print(i+1, '- ', 'добавить/удалить очки к характеристике -', skill_l[1][i])
    print('0 -  выход')


def add_rem(n):
    global skill_l
    global skill_p
    print('Укажите количество очков, которые необходимо добавить к характеристике '+str(skill_l[1][n-1])+'(0 для выхода из режима):')
    try:
        c = int(input())
    except:
        print('Необходимо указывать целое число. Для удаления очков необходимо указать перед числом знак минус.')
        return False
    if skill_p - c >= 0 and skill_l[0][n-1] + c >= 0:
        skill_p = skill_p - c
        skill_l[0][n - 1] = skill_l[0][n - 1] + c
    else:
        print('Недостаточно очков характеристик для переаспределения')

while just_do_it:
    show_stats()
    show_list()
    try:
        c = int(input())
    except:
        print('Ошибочный выбор пункта меню')
        continue
    if c < 0 or c > 4:
        print('Ошибочный выбор пункта меню')
        continue
    if c == 0:
        just_do_it = False
        break
    while add_rem(c) == False:
        pass
```